# Resize Decal Based On Distance From Another GameObject

Tags: unity, textures, sprites

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

- I am trying to recreate Paper Mario's "fake" shadow effect for my game.
- All of the characters in Paper Mario have a sprite of a dark circle that follows their character and scales depending on the character's distance in the Y-axis.

**What I've done so far:**

- I've created a URP Decal Projector and made it a child of my character so that it will follow them. I've increased the Projection Depth so that it will still be in range of the ground when the character jumps.

---

**What I need assistance with:**

- I need the decal resize to be smaller as the character is higher in the Y-Axis. Just like the example below:

[image]

---

Thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: Since this website is a one-question-per-thread site, you should split up this thread into 3 threads - one thread per task you need help with. So edit this thread, save the first task in this and then move the other tasks to their own threads.

Comment: I can only help you with the first task at the moment.
I would suggest scaling down the shadow sprite based on the distance (in Y direction) between the character and the shadow sprite. So every frame, check the distance between them and subtract that from the shadow sprite. Whenever the character jumps, the shadow sprite should then scale up/down based on the distance. You might want to set a limit on how big/small the shadow sprite can be by clamping the scale value between a min- and a max value.

Comment: @Daniel_1985 Your second comment sounds like the a solid basis for posting an answer.

Comment: @Daniel_1985 Good call! I've edited the thread to focus on my first task.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking 3 questions as long as each question is its own topic (and not asking three times the same thing since nobody replied the first two times). Some people might be able to just help with one of your points while others with others. There is no need to wait until the first question is answered

Comment: I was able to get most of the effect I want by creating a URP Decal Projector! I've updated my initial post to reflect where I'm at.